# Required IAM permissions for ec2.requestSpotInstances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to set permissions on an IAM role that will submit a new spot instance request if needed. It will be used by a Lambda function.

The code does the following AWS API calls:

- ec2.describeSpotInstanceRequests
- ec2.requestSpotInstances
- ec2.createTags

And I created for it the following policy (after trying a lot of other options...):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1437749945000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:Describe*",
            "ec2:RequestSpotInstances",
            "ec2:RunInstances",
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "iam:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

If I add `iam:*` it works, but obviously I don't want to do that..

Can anyone help me guessing what permission it really needs? Does anyone know of a map between AWS API calls and all required permissions?

Comment: Does the error message not tell you ?

Comment: No. It just says "You're not authorized to perform this action". I know.. really helpful...

Comment: Are you assigning an Iam role to the instance?

Comment: Of course. As I said, if I add 'iam:*' to the role it works but I clearly don't want to do that but add only the required one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting an instance that has an IAM role specified, you need the `iam:PassRole` permission.

The resource should be the arn for the role, usually of the form `arn:aws:iam::012345678912:role/role_name`.

Comment: Thanks! finally... `PassRole` isn't documented in their *latest* IAM API reference.